# How to make some specific row in embedding matrix equal to zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create an embedding matrix to embed my data. However in my data, I used 0 as the padding. Therefore I want to make the embedding for 0 take a specific constant value, which is zero vector. How can I do that?

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
check_vector=tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0, dtype=tf.int32)
embedding_matrix=tf.get_variables("emb",[20,30]
embedding_result=tf.gather(check_vector,embedding_result)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.gather(embedding_matrix, check_vector))
```

Comment: Can you add an example? Given an input of X, what is the output, y, that you expect? What have you tried and what did/ didn't work?

Comment: My example is already in my code. You can see the vector is [1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0]. I use tf.gather to get the embedding of check_vector from embedding_matrix. As 0 is padding, i want its embedding is zeros vector and not be changed when do the backpropagation. I try to set first row of embedding_matrix: embedding_matrix[0]=tf.constants([0]*30) but it does not work

Comment: What's the expected output